# How to set encoding in SOAP-Request?

Tags: c#, soap, .net-core

I’m trying to consume a webservice in .NET Core 2.0 by using SOAP. The client for the webservice was generated with the “Connected Service”-feature of Visual Studio.

Now I have the problem, that the webservice needs in the request the (first) line with the encoding-Attribute:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

I’ve tried many different ways to write this line in the output-XML, but nothing works.

#### First approach:

I added a new endpoint behavior (by implementing IEndpointBehavior) to the client with using a customized message inspector (by implementing IClientMessageInspector). Via debugging I found out, the message object contains the said line. But by writing the outgoing XML to the webservice, the line is missing.

#### Second approach:

I wrote a customized message encoding binding element with a wsdl export extension (by using MessageEncodingBindingElement & IWsdlExportExtension) . This binding element uses a customized MessageEncoder where the encoding is set explicitly. I added the binding to the generated client.

Here are some .net 4.6 code snippets:

```
// Binding for the client
TextMessageBindingElement textBindingElement = new TextMessageBindingElement();
textBindingElement.Encoding = "utf-8";
textBindingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;
textBindingElement.MediaType = "text/xml";

bindingElements.Add(textBindingElement);

CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
```

---

```
// Customized Message Binding Element for encoding
public class TextMessageBindingElement : MessageEncodingBindingElement, 
IWsdlExportExtension {

    public override MessageVersion MessageVersion { get; set; }
    public string Encoding { get; set; }

    ...

    public override MessageEncoderFactory CreateMessageEncoderFactory() {
        return new TextMessageEncoderFactory(MediaType, Encoding, MessageVersion);
    }

    void ExportContract(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlContractConversionContext context) {
    }

    void ExportEndpoint(WsdlExporter exporter, WsdlEndpointConversionContext context) {
         TextMessageEncodingBindingElement mebe = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
         mebe.MessageVersion = this.msgVersion;
         ((IWsdlExportExtension) mebe).ExportEndpoint(exporter, context);
    }
}
```

In .NET 4.6 this works, but .NET Core 2.0 doesn’t support IWsdlExportExtension. I’ve searched for alternatives, but haven’t found anything yet.

Please, can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you saying that the generated SOAP request does not contain an `<?xml...>` header at all? That's weird, a SOAP message is an XML document. Can you show us what your client is currently sending over the wire?